# ^[0-9.9]{0,6} - How can I make this only accept numbers up to 100?

Tags: range

Obviously this is accepting each number as input but what I don't know how to do is to make this accept numbers up to 100.  Trying to solve for it recognizing the number as individual digits rather that up to 3 numbers from 0 - 100.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

\b([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)\b.{0,5}